# Keep an object as a value in Redis using its HashTable

Tags: caching, redis, binding, stackexchange.redis

I am new to Redis and I'm trying to write a simple project that collects information from SQL database and caches into Redis. As I'm more comfortable with C#, I've chosen ***StackExchange.Redis*** to do that.

Let's say I have a table in my db with a schema like this **Persons(ID, Name, Address, Age, BirthDate)**.
I have a **Person** class in my project with corresponding fields.
I have also a function **GetPersonByID(ID)**, that requests the Redis, if a key with the ID *doesn't* exist it executes another function called **GetPersonByID_SQL(ID)**, when an sql query is being executed, after getting information from db it creates an object **Person**, adds that object to Redis(using hashTable) and returns the object. If the key existed in Redis the function just gets information from Redis, creates an object **Person**, maps the corresponding values values to fields and returns that object.

Here is the code of how I do this.

```
public static Person GetPersonByID(string ID)
        {
            redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1");
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
            Person p;

            if (!db.KeyExists(key))
            {
                p = Person.GetPersonByID_SQL(ID);
                db.HashSet(key, "Name", p.Name);
                db.HashSet(key, "Address", p.Address);
                db.HashSet(key, "Age", p.Age);
                db.HashSet(key, "BirthDate", p.BirthDate); 
            }
            else
            {
                HashEntry[] values = db.HashGetAll(key);
                p = new Person();

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    HashEntry hashEntry = values[i];
                    switch (hashEntry.Name)
                    {
                        case "Name": p.Name = hashEntry.Value; break;
                        case "Address": p.Address = hashEntry.Value; break;
                        case "Age": p.Age = hashEntry.Value; break;
                        case "BirthDate": p.BirthDate = hashEntry.Value; break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return p;
        }
```

My question is, Is there any way I can Bind automatically the value of Redis (that is in my way a HashTable) to my existing object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, Is there any way I can Bind automatically the value of Redis (that is in my way a HashTable) to my existing object?

No, this is not a feature of StackExchange.Redis - values can only be stored as the most basic types (strings and numbers). You're expected to do the conversions to more complex values yourself.

So you can either store your person object as multiple hash fields (as you've done in your code), or you can store your person object as a single serialized string against a key (you can use the STRING data structure for this instead). Then you can perform the necessary deserializations when you want to retrieve a value.

If you always want to retrieve every value from your Person data structure, I would recommend going for the second option. You'll only then need to use a single command command for each get/set:

```
// SET
_redis.StringSet(key, serializedPerson);

// GET
string serializedPerson = _redis.StringGet(key);
```